# Does the size of the data increases after upgrading the sstables in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

We upgraded the DSE 3.x.x to DSE 4.x.x. The upgraded was successful but the data in the cluster was doubled and I ran the repair and cleanup but still no use.

Is this is the normal behavior? how to regain the space? or is there a way to calculate how much data was inserted in last one day?

I still see some old sstables are not upgraded to new sstables in 1 node. I tried to run the scrub and upgradesstables on the keyspace and CF but the old sstables are not deleted. How to upgrade these old sstables?

Answer (score 0):

Where are the SSTables which haven't been upgraded? If the keyspace or column family no longer exists then they will not be upgraded. When upgrading the SSTables the normal process is to rewrite the data into new SSTables and delete the old ones, but it shouldn't cause an immediate doubling of space consumed.

There's no real way of telling how much data was inserted within the last day or so. The best way to estimate that would be to monitor writes to your application through opscenter or directly with JMX and estimate that number.